# Efficiently multiply sparse and dense matrix

Tags: intel-mkl

How to multiply a sparse matrix and a dense matrix efficiently?
Does setting zero to beta for the [mkl_dcsrmm](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468594) function makes the function takes less time?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can trust MKL that it gives best solution on various inputs.

Comment: but that function does C := alpha*A*B + beta*C where A is sparse, B is dense, C is dense, and alpha and beta are scalar constants. Instead of just doing C = A*B.

Comment: I mean if C=AB is faster than C=AB+C, developers of MKL will create a separate code path for the case of `beta==0`

Comment: thanks i will work on calling that mkl function from python then.